# Find an algorithm to balance this game

Tags: algorithm

I've tried to extract just the part of the problem where I'm having trouble, this is part of a bigger project that I'm doing (not homework). I think it's easiest to describe it as a game (since I need it to finish a game I'm working on). This is a one player game the way I'm describing it.

**START** You start with one of two positions:

- weight `(2,0,-1)` and one `red` play
- weight `(3,1,-1)` and two `red` plays

**END** The game ends when you have no more plays. The goal is to end the game with weight `(0,0,0)`.

There are two types of plays `red` and `blue`. Given a play, you choose one of four pieces: `A,B,C,D` that give you additional weight and possibly additional plays. Here are the rules:

- On a `red` play:

  - A adds weight `(0,-2,-1)`
  - B adds weight `(1,-1,-1)` and adds one `red` play
  - C adds weight `(2,0,-1)` and two `red` plays
  - D adds weight `(0,2,1)` and two `blue` plays

The rules for `blue` plays are similar but the first two columns for weights are swapped and the last column is reverse and the types of plays are reversed, so you get this instead:

- On a `blue` play:

  - A adds weight `(-2,0,1)`
  - B adds weight `(-1,1,1)` and adds one `blue` play
  - C adds weight `(0,2,1)` and two `blue` plays
  - D adds weight `(2,0,-1)` and two `red` plays

**QUESTION** Can this game be won?

I'm trying to write a program that wins the game by choosing plays so that the final balance is `(0,0,0)` when you have no more plays. Only I can't seem to do it. So now I think that maybe there is no algorithm to win the game. I'd really like to know why that is. If anyone has any ideas how I can prove that, then please let me know!! Or, if you try it and find a way to win, then please tell me that, too. Thanks!!

Comment: To confirm - you begin with `(1, 0, 0)` and a randomly-colored play?  Also, are all the pieces available to you at each step, or do you only get each piece once, or are you given a randomly-chosen set of pieces?

Comment: @templatetypedef Sorry, I had the starting conditions wrong. I've edited the details so its right now.

Comment: What happens when you try to brute force it by enumerating through all possible moves?

Comment: @mbeckish I've been running that for over a week and I still haven't found a solution, which is why I think the game is probably unwinable.

Comment: How have you been doing it?  Breadth-first?

Comment: @Fantius Both. I have BFS on one processor and DFS on the other.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what happens to the absolute sum of weights? (x,y,z) -> |x| + |y| + |z|

Comment: How is the starting position chosen?  Random or selected by the player?

Comment: @Fantius There are only the two possible starting positions. I can't find a solution for either.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with C, so I removed the tag.

Comment: I think your search program has a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably I'm missing something, but just by inspection, it looks like this sequence of steps should work? :

- start with "weight `(2,0,-1)` and one `red` play"
- take a `red` play, piece `C`, which "adds weight `(2,0,-1)` and two `red` plays", leaving you with weight `(4,0,-2)` and two `red` plays.
- take a `red` play, piece `A`, which "adds weight `(0,-2,-1)`", leaving you with weight `(4,-2,-3)` and one `red` play.
- take a `red` play, piece `D`, which "adds weight `(0,2,1)` and two `blue` plays", leaving you with weight `(4,0,-2)` and two `blue` plays.
- take a `blue` play, piece `A`, which "adds weight `(-2,0,1)`", leaving you with weight `(2,0,-1)` and one `blue` play.
- take a `blue` play, piece `A`, which "adds weight `(-2,0,1)`", leaving you with weight `(0,0,0)` and no plays.

A bit more schematically:

```
move        weight         plays
------      ---------      -------
            (2,0,-1)       red
red C       (4,0,-2)       red x2
red A       (4,-2,-3)      red
red D       (4,0,-2)       blue x2
blue A      (2,0,-1)       blue
blue A      (0,0,0)        -
```

. . . no?

---

**Edited to add:**

*How I Found This:*

Since this question has garnered a lot of interest, maybe I should explain how I found the above solution. It was basically luck; I happened upon two key observations:

- `red A` and `red D` cancel each other out weight-wise (the former adds `(0,-2,-1)`, the latter adds `(0,2,1)`), and add a total of two `blue` plays (both from `red D`) and no `red` plays; so if you play one right after the other, you "convert" two `red` plays into two `blue` plays.
- `blue A` cancels out the initial weight (it adds `(2,0,-1)`) and adds no plays, so the entire problem can be solved by "converting" one `red` play into one `blue` play.

That gave me a good start. I started with `red C` so as to get the two `red` plays that I could "convert" to two `blue` plays, and I immediately saw that `red C` was also the "opposite" of `blue A` weight-wise, so could also be canceled with a `blue A`. In my head, it all seemed to cancel out perfectly; then I wrote it down to make sure.

*Proof That It's Minimal:*

Also, while I didn't bother to reason through it at the time, I can also prove that this is a "minimal" winning sequence for that starting position — by which I mean, that if a sequence starts with "weight `(2,0,-1)` and one `red` play" and ends with weight `(0,0,0)` and no plays, then the sequence must contain at least five moves. To do so, assume that we have a sequence that meets this condition and has *fewer* than five moves. Then:

1. Since the first component of the weight starts out positive, and no `red` play decreases it, the sequence will require at least one `blue` play, which means that it will necessarily include `red D` at least once (since that's the only way to acquire a `blue` play if you don't start out with one).
2. Since the sequence includes `red D` at least once, and `red D` gives us two `blue` plays, the sequence will necessarily include `blue` at least twice (since the game doesn't end until no plays remain).
3. Since the sequence includes `red D` at least once, and `red D` adds 2 to the second component of the weight, it will necessarily either contain `red A` at least once, or else contain `red B` at least twice (since there is no other way to decrease the second component of the weight by at least 2). But clearly, if it contains `red D` at least once, `blue` at least twice, and `red B` at least twice, then it will contain at least five moves, which is forbidden by assumption; so it must use the `red A` approach.
4. So, the sequence contains `red D` at least once, `blue` at least twice, and `red A` at least once. And by assumption, it contains fewer than five moves. So it must consist of *exactly* one `red D`, two `blue`s, one `red A`, and zero other moves.
5. The starting position gives us only one `red` play, and the sequence includes exactly two `red` plays. Therefore, the sequence must contain a move that yields exactly one `red` play. But the only possible move that could do that is `red B`, which the sequence doesn't contain.

Therefore, no such sequence is possible.

*The Other Starting Position:*

I can also prove, using similar sorts of arguments, that any solution starting with the "weight `(3,1,-1)` and two `red` plays" option must also contain at least five moves. One such five-move solution is:

```
move        weight         plays
------      ---------      -------
            (3,1,-1)       red x2
red A       (3,-1,-2)      red
red B       (4,-2,-3)      red
red D       (4,0,-2)       blue x2
blue A      (2,0,-1)       blue
blue A      (0,0,0)        -
```

Comment: Thank you! The only problem now is that this answer doesn't work when I plug it back into the original problem that I'm working on. I'll have to see what's wrong there, but this looks like an answer to me. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 6):

Here are solutions for each starting position:

```
Start 1: (2, 0, -1)  Reds=1  Blues=0
Red B ==> (3, -1, -2)  Reds=1  Blues=0
Red B ==> (4, -2, -3)  Reds=1  Blues=0
Red D ==> (4, 0, -2)  Reds=0  Blues=2
Blue A ==> (2, 0, -1)  Reds=0  Blues=1
Blue A ==> (0, 0, 0)  Reds=0  Blues=0

Start 2: (3, 1, -1)  Reds=2  Blues=0
Red A ==> (3, -1, -2)  Reds=1  Blues=0
Red B ==> (4, -2, -3)  Reds=1  Blues=0
Red D ==> (4, 0, -2)  Reds=0  Blues=2
Blue A ==> (2, 0, -1)  Reds=0  Blues=1
Blue A ==> (0, 0, 0)  Reds=0  Blues=0
```

Found instantly by the following C# program that does a random walk and gives up after a small number of moves.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SO8683939
{
  struct State
  {
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
    public int V3;
    public int Reds;
    public int Blues;
    public int Tokens { get { return Reds + Blues; } }
    public string Description;
    public State(int v1, int v2, int v3, int reds, int blues)
    {
      V1 = v1;
      V2 = v2;
      V3 = v3;
      Reds = reds;
      Blues = blues;
      Description = null;
    }
    public State Add(State other)
    {
      State sum;
      sum.V1 = V1 + other.V1;
      sum.V2 = V2 + other.V2;
      sum.V3 = V3 + other.V3;
      sum.Reds = Reds + other.Reds;
      sum.Blues = Blues + other.Blues;
      sum.Description = null;
      return sum;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
      var detail = string.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})  Reds={3}  Blues={4}", V1, V2, V3, Reds, Blues);
      if (Description != null)
      {
        return Description + ": " + detail;
      }
      return detail;
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var start1 = new State(2, 0, -1, 1, 0) { Description = "Start 1" };
      var start2 = new State(3, 1, -1, 2, 0) { Description = "Start 2" };

      var end = new State(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

      var redA = new State(0, -2, -1, -1, 0) { Description = "Red A" };
      var redB = new State(1, -1, -1, 0, 0) { Description = "Red B" }; ;
      var redC = new State(2, 0, -1, 1, 0) { Description = "Red C" }; ;
      var redD = new State(0, 2, 1, -1, 2) { Description = "Red D" }; ;
      var redOptions = new[] { redA, redB, redC, redD };

      var blueA = new State(-2, 0, 1, 0, -1) { Description = "Blue A" };
      var blueB = new State(-1, 1, 1, 0, 0) { Description = "Blue B" };
      var blueC = new State(0, 2, 1, 0, 1) { Description = "Blue C" };
      var blueD = new State(2, 0, -1, 2, -1) { Description = "Blue D" };
      var blueOptions = new[] { blueA, blueB, blueC, blueD };

      var startingPosition = start1;
      var maxSolutionLength = 5;

      var rand = new Random();
      var path = new List<State>();
      while (true)
      {
        var current = startingPosition;
        path.Clear();
        //Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        //Console.WriteLine(current);
        while (true)
        {
          State selected;
          if (current.Reds == 0)
          {
            selected = blueOptions[rand.Next(4)];
          }
          else if (current.Blues == 0)
          {
            selected = redOptions[rand.Next(4)];
          }
          else
          {
            if (rand.NextDouble() < 0.5)
            {
              selected = blueOptions[rand.Next(4)];
            }
            else
            {
              selected = redOptions[rand.Next(4)];
            }
          }
          //Console.WriteLine(selected);
          path.Add(selected);
          current = current.Add(selected);
          //Console.WriteLine(current);
          if (current.Equals(end))
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            var retrace = startingPosition;
            Console.WriteLine(retrace);
            foreach (var selection in path)
            {
              retrace = retrace.Add(selection);
              Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", selection.Description, retrace);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
          }
          else if (current.Tokens == 0)
          {
            // fail
            //Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            break;
          }
          else if (path.Count >= maxSolutionLength)
          {
            // fail
            //Console.WriteLine("Fail");
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Consider the number of red and blue plays to be two additional dimensions to your position.**  This greatly reduces the complexity of the problem.

*Below, the problem is restated with the last two dimensions representing red and blue plays remaining.*

**START** You start with one of two positions:

- weight `(2, 0,-1, 1, 0)`
- weight `(3,-1,-1, 2, 0)`

**END** The game ends when you have weight `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Given a play, you choose one of eight pieces: `Ar,Br,Cr,Dr,Ab,Bb,Cb,Db` that give you additional weight. Here are the rules:

- Ar adds weight `(0,-2,-1,-1, 0)`
- Br adds weight `(1,-1,-1, 0, 0)`
- Cr adds weight `(2, 0,-1, 1, 0)`
- Dr adds weight `(0, 2, 1,-1, 2)`
- Ab adds weight `(-2,0, 1, 0,-1)`
- Bb adds weight `(-1,1, 1, 0, 0)`
- Cb adds weight `(0, 2, 1, 0, 1)`
- Db adds weight `(2, 0,-1, 2,-1)`

Furthermore, the last two dimensions may never be negative.

**Now, it may be solved as an 8-variable equation.**

Comment: This is a nice way to reformulate the problem, but it doesn't get me any closer to solving it, does it?

Comment: In the worst case, you can formulate this as an integer program.  Solving IP's is NP-hard, but this at least means that it's not undecidably hard.

Comment: But how can I know if there is a solution? I've been searching for one for over a week. Is there any way to know if there is an answer without finding it?

Comment: One approach is to build a tree with all possible permutations of moves and prune it when you detect duplicate configurations.  It's brute force, but it is sound.  You'll have to decide how many levels deep you want to try before abandoning that approach though.

Comment: Neat, but slightly incomplete: the "last two may never be negative" restriction is insufficient to express the idea that you can only play the first four moves if your `red` variable is greater than 0. (i.e. even though `Br` and `Cr` have a net non-negative effect, you still can't play them if you have zero `red` moves.)

Comment: @tzaman: You're right.  Do you see a simple way to account for that?